# replicate plot() using ggplot()

Tags: r, ggplot2

Please see attached plots using the standard `plot()` function vs `ggplot()` function.

[image: plot()]
[image: ggplot()]

I am currently playing around with `theme()` to try and replicate the `plot()` background/panels and general look etc. but I can't get it quite right.

I've tried:

`theme_update(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white", colour = "grey50"))`

But it's not quite what I'm looking for and it reverts back to the gray background whenever I relaunch RStudio....

Any helpful pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Package  ggthemes has `theme_base` and I think you only need to add shape = 1 in `geom_point()` for the hollow points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following my comment I provide a reproducible example using diamonds dataset:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggthemes)

set.seed(100)
mydata <- diamonds[sample(nrow(diamonds), 100), ]   

ggplot(data = mydata, aes(x = carat, y = price)) +
  geom_point(shape = 1) +
  theme_base()
```

[image]